# Will my app break if dependencies it uses are modified or deleted?

Tags: android, gradle

I am building an app that uses [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), so I have added this library as a dependency using Gradle, as explained [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#gradle-setup).

Is my app at risk of no longer working if the library's creator deletes the library from the online repository, or modifies it? Does Gradle copy the library source code into my project, so that I can build (and re-build) my app using the library, as long as I have my Android Studio project saved locally?

Answer (score 2):

Importing an Android library practically downloads all the functionalities that come with using that library into your application/project at the very `version` the library was in when you imported it.

From the word `import`, it means you are getting a copy into your project for use. Even if the owner of the library deletes the main source codes, as long as you have imported them, you can still use the imported functions the library has to offer at whatever version you imported the library.

When the maintainer/s of the library release a new version say from `1.1.X.X` to `1.2.X.X`, you'll need to update the version you imported to `1.2.X.X` if you need the new functionalites that have been added in the update. Most of the time, gradle shows you something like this to let you know there is a new version:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Do you have a reference you can cite, that says the same thing as your answer?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't any docs to really explain this. I have re-edited the answer to put in more clarity :)